# MotionEvent up doesn't work outside of button

Tags: android

I have an ImageButton when i press it and keep my finger down it becomes invisible, when i lift my finger it becomes visible again.

But when i press the button and while my finger is down i move it away from it and lift it up it doesn't become visible again

The code looks like this

```
final ImageButton b=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.timer_btn);

        b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.w("app", "Action up");
                        return true;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                        b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.w("app", "Action down");

                       }
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

I tried using

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: 
                            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Log.w("app", "Action outside");

                           }
```

but it doesn't work, it gets called no matter if it's outside the button or inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the `ACTION_CANCEL`.
I guess the ACTION_OUSIDE is for outside the actual screen.

The system will always calls either the UP or the CANCEL.

**edit:**

I believe this should work:

```
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.w("app", "Action up");
                    return true;
```

Comment: Ohh i was using ACTION_CANCEL at the end and it didn't work, but when i've moved it before the ACTION_UP it worked, you might wanna update your answer telling to put it as the first case, so someone with the same problem might do it more easily :)

Comment: yes it works, first case ACTION_CANCEL, then ACTION_UP, then ACTION_DOWN, using ACTION_CANCEL at the end won't work